# Swift Delegate returns unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

Setting up my delegate within the protocol continues to throw nil. I have attempted numerous approaches suggested in other posts. I am attempting to get my protocol + delegate up and running, however, unable to solve why it continues to throw nil.

Force unwrapping, calling the delegate from various locations in the file, removing & adding Weak Var.

List View:

```
protocol MixPlayer : class {
    func playMix(message: String)
}


class IssueViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var issueCollection: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var issueImage: UIImageView!

    var viewController: ViewController?

    var collectionViewtitle: String?
    var mixImageName: String?

    var mixList: [[String: String]]!

    weak var mixDelegate: MixPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        issueCollection.dataSource = self
        issueCollection.delegate = self

    }

}
....

extension IssueViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

....

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let url = mixList[indexPath.row]["url"] {
            mixDelegate?.playMix(message: url)
        }
    }   
}
```

View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController  {
    @IBOutlet weak var mainContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerEmbedView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let secondVC = IssueViewController()
        secondVC.mixDelegate = self

    }
}

extension ViewController: MixPlayer {
    func playMix(message: String) {
        print(message)
    }
}
```

Any attempt at calling

```
mixDelegate?.playMix(message: url)
```

Is unsuccessful. Currently I'm just trying to log basic print statements.

Comment: Which line is crashing?

Comment: In `ViewController viewDidLoad` your `secondVC` gets deallocated at the end of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: You need to set the delegate on the actual instance of `IssueViewController` that is on screen, not an instance that you just create (and that is almost immediately released). How do you get to `IssueViewController` from `ViewController`?

Comment: @rmaddy crashing on mixDelegate?.playMix call -- I attempted to print deinit from ViewController and no result was logged. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It can't be crashing on that line as written since you are not force-unwrapping any optional with `mixDelegate?.playMix(message: url)` unless `url` is an implicitly unwrapped optional and it's nil.

Comment: Be aware the the default initializer `IssueViewController()` returns a new instance which is **not** the instance in the storyboard. In this new instance the outlets are not connected. You need the reference to the instance in the storyboard from a segue or by instantiating the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your `secondVC` inside the `ViewController` gets deallocated. Make that a property in your `ViewController`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController  {
    @IBOutlet weak var mainContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerEmbedView: UIView!

    lazy var secondVC: IssueViewController = {
        let secondVC = IssueViewController()
        secondVC.mixDelegate = self
        return secondVC
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    ... 
}
```

To know if your class gets deallocated, add a deinit with a print statement on it.

```
deinit {
    print("Deallocated")
}
```

Comment: Thank you, attempted the update with no luck. deinit does not call from Viewcontroller, but when I place within IssueViewController it prints when leaving that view.